# Copy Sum on Excel status bar with macro, shows error when windows explorer is open

Tags: excel

I have this macro that is assigned to a ribbon button that copies the sum of a selected range from the status bar so i can use it elsewhere:

```
  Sub CopySUM()
     Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
       On Error GoTo BailOut
       DataObj.SetText 
       Application.Sum(Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
       DataObj.PutInClipboard
       BailOut:
   End Sub
```

It works ok till i have windows explorer open. It will then only paste error squares [?][?] . Does anyone knows why this occur or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Damn i just realised excel 365 you just need to click the status bar...

no need for this anymore!